# React Router Switch not showing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a website in react and am using router-dom to have the correct url showing.

I have a navbar that links to an about page using Link to="" and then using Switch and Route to display the component for the correct path, but it doesn't work.

Not sure if I missed anything here but I can't manage to display any components.

**This is my PageContainer**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Alphabet from "./Alphabet";
import About from "./About";


export default class PageContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <section className="pagecontainer">
          <Switch>

            <Route exact path="/omoss">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Alphabet />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </section>
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my navbar**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <section>
          <section className="navbar">
            <Link to="/">Hem</Link>
            <Link to="/omoss">OM OSS</Link>
          </section>
        </section>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

- Removed `BrowserRouter` from both components above.
- Changed App.js to below.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import PageContainer from "./components/PageContainer";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <section className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <PageContainer />
      </section>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Still not working though. The url changes but the components doesn't show.

**UPDATE 2**

Think I solved it when I removed two other components that where showing in `Switch` inside `PageContainer` but weren't in a `Route`. I had removed them before uploading here but forgot them in my code

Comment: You don't need router in your navbar

Answer (score 2):

You have two individual `<BrowserRouter />` components, each with its own state. I suggest that you move the `<BrowserRouter />` component to a common ancestor of both `<Navbar />` and `<PageContainer />` so that they can share the same history object.

For example, remove the BrowserRouter from your components and place it higher in the component hierarchy. Now, both `<Navbar />` and `<PageContainer />` are in the scope of the same `<BrowserRouter />`

```
function App() {
  return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <PageContainer />
     </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see! How is it possible to move ```<BrowserRouter />``` to a component that can be used from both? How would that look like?

Comment: Second to this, if the intention was to have **nested routes*,* then another approach outside the scope of the question would be needed. Otherwise, your root file (succeeding your entry file), would be the comment ancestor node that should be wrapped in a router.

An example: 

` const Root = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
) `

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how it can be achieved.

Comment: I changed it to that. You can see my updated edit on the original post. Still not showing though for some reason

Comment: the code looks fine from purely react perspective, so there must be something else at play. What kind of dev server are you using? You can also share the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you both for helping! I updated what besides wrong usage of ```BrowserRouter``` was messing things up.

Comment: great, glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `BrowserRouter` in `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import PageContainer from "./components/PageContainer";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <section className="App">
        <PageContainer />
        <Navbar />
      </section>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Then I get this error: Cannot use ```Link``` outside ```Router```, if I remove ```BrowserRouter```

Comment: Isn't your `Navbar` component wrap inside `BrowserRouter`? In some parent component

Comment: I have App.js with two components ```Navbar```and ```PageContainer```. The second one has ```BrowserRouter``` inside, but not in App.js. If I move ```Navbar``` from App.js to inside ```BrowserRouter``` then I might be able to use your example above?

Comment: Yes! you've to wrap your `App` component inside `BrowserRouter`. And don't forget to remove `BrowserRouter` from `PageContainer` component

Comment: Updated the post above to what I think you mean. Still not showing though. I added ```BrowserRouter``` to ```App``` and removed it from previous two components

Comment: I've updated my answer. @JossifElefteriadis

Comment: I updated my answer that I found what the problem was, besides using ```BrowserRouter``` the wrong way. Thank you for helping!